# Unity: Project/Draw 3d object onto 2d plane

Tags: unity-game-engine, opengl, graphics

I want to recreate something like the image below. I created a `quad`, placed it in front of the camera, then added a `WebCamTexture` to play the camera feed on the 2d plane.

I then want to place a 3d object, say a cube, in between the 2d plane and the camera, and project/draw the 3d object onto the 2d plane. How can I accomplish this in Unity? What are the basic steps?

Also, would doing something like this be possible using OpenGL? Would it be complex? What are the basic steps?

[image]

Comment: *would doing something like this be possible using OpenGL? Would it be complex?* - yes, and depends on what you mean by "complex".